# How to I register Akka Typed actors to Receptionist with dynamic keys?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-typed

I would like to have multiple instances of the same Akka actor but with a specific "config" and name each.
I though about using the Receptionist pattern and register like this :

```
object PingService {

  final case class Ping(replyTo: ActorRef[Pong.type])
  case object Pong

  def apply(id: String): Behavior[Ping] = {
    Behaviors.setup { context =>
      context.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(ServiceKey[Ping](s"pingService-$id"), context.self)
      val config = getConfig(id)
      Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case Ping(replyTo) =>
          context.log.info("Pinged by {}", replyTo)
          replyTo ! Pong
          Behaviors.same
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I though about lookup using `Receptionist.Find(ServiceKey[Ping]("pingService-12345"))`

```
Behaviors
.receiveMessage {
    case ListingResponse(listing) =>
       //call refs from listing
       Behaviors.same
}
```

But it does not seem to be the way as it is not working.
And receive the listing like this :

How could I achieve this and is the Receptionist the right pattern for this use case?

Comment: It's not clear from this what exactly isn't working, but I'd note that the `Receptionist` is unlikely to efficiently handle much more than a few thousand distinct `ServiceKey`s.  If you're clustering, I'd probably use cluster sharding for this; for a purely local experience (which you're not going to get without some effort via the `Receptionist`), defining an actor which resolves and manages the instances of the general actor is probably a good approach.

Comment: I mean that if I use a new instance of `ServiceKey` every time, even with the right key, the actor won't be found/listed; However, if instead I do register and `Find()` the actor using the variable (something like `PingService.key` (equal to `ServiceKey[Ping]("pingService")`)), then `Find` will retrieve a ListingResponse containing the PingService that has previously been registered.

Comment: Looking through the implementation, since `ServiceKey[Ping]("pingService-12345")` constructs a `case class` with just the strings `"pingService-12345"` and `"Ping"`, it shouldn't matter if you're constructing a new `ServiceKey` per `Find` or using a static one.  Has an actor for that `ServiceKey` been spawned?

Comment: Ok, thanks! It' also what I could understand from the implementation and documentation, but as I could not make it work with a local receptionist, as you noticed (and haven't tried with cluster)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this, at least with the local receptionist.

```
import akka.actor.typed._
import akka.actor.typed.receptionist._
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object PingService {
  final case class Ping(replyTo: ActorRef[Pong.type])
  case object Pong

  def apply(id: Int): Behavior[Ping] =
    Behaviors.setup { context =>
      context.system.receptionist ! Receptionist.Register(
        ServiceKey[Ping](s"pingService-$id"),
        context.self
      )
      println(s"PingService instance $id spawned")
      Behaviors.receiveMessage { msg =>
        msg match {
          case Ping(replyTo) =>
            println(s"PingService $id ponging $replyTo")
            replyTo ! Pong
            Behaviors.same
        }
      }
    }
}

object Guardian {
  case class SpawnPingService(id: Int)

  val behavior = Behaviors.receive[SpawnPingService] { (context, msg) =>
    msg match {
      case SpawnPingService(id) =>
        context.spawn(PingService(id), s"ping-service-$id")
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}

object Main {
  import akka.util.Timeout
  import AskPattern._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem(Guardian.behavior, "main")

    implicit val dispatcher = system.executionContext

    system ! Guardian.SpawnPingService(42)
    system ! Guardian.SpawnPingService(96)

    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(
      10.seconds,
      () => {
        implicit val timeout: Timeout = 10.seconds
        implicit val sys: ActorSystem[_] = system

        // using the ask pattern, but you can provide any
        // ActorRef[Receptionist.Listing], including a message adapter, etc.
        val result: Future[Receptionist.Listing] =
          system.receptionist.ask { replyTo =>
          Receptionist.Find(ServiceKey[PingService.Ping]("pingService-42"), replyTo)
        }

        result.foreach { listing =>
          val serviceInstances =
            listing.serviceInstances(ServiceKey[PingService.Ping]("pingService-42"))
          println(s"Found $serviceInstances")
          val pongFut = serviceInstances.head.ask(PingService.Ping(_))

          pongFut.foreach { pong =>
            println("got ponged from PingService #42")

            system.terminate
          }
        }
      }
    )

    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(
      40.seconds,
      () => {
        system.terminate()
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Note that when sending a `Find` to the system receptionist, only actors which had registered with that receptionist to that point will be found.  In the case of a cluster, there is a potentially unbounded delay between registration and that registration being seen on all nodes in the cluster.

As for whether the receptionist is a good idea for this sort of thing, it's much more suited for the case when there are many actors per `ServiceKey` than when there are many thousands of `ServiceKey`s.  In a cluster case, if looking to have many instances of the same actor with distinct identity, Cluster Sharding is probably better (and it will spawn the sharded actors on demand).

Comment: thanks a lot for the example! As I don't plan to clusterize, it might not work for me, right? Also, I am not totally sure that *must* use akka typed, I could stay with "classic" Akka and use actorSelection. However if I sticl to Akka typed and might not use a cluster, do you think using a HashMap that keeps the references would be alright? (in any case, I will only have maximum 10 or 20 instances at a time)

Comment: For a local shard situation, the receptionist should work, but you can also define (probably without much difficulty) an actor which supports lookups (as with the receptionist) and also spawns a child actor to fulfill a lookup if there isn't one needed (as in sharding).